# Оставить запятую в строке - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, массивы, регулярные-выражения, node.js

Здравствуйте, несколько дней бьюсь над регуляркой (node.js) с функцией replace, которая из числа: 299,00 р. должна удалить - р.(слова) и оставить чисто с запятой: 299,00, но вместо запятой он выводит в лог 29900 игнорируя запятую, помогите пожалуйста!
Вод сам код:

```
var needle = require('needle');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var templayed = require('templayed');
var fs = require('fs');
var schema = require("semantic-schema-parser");


var Scraping = new function(){
    //1. Подключаемся к БД
    _this = this;
    _this.DB = mysql.createConnection({
          host     : 'localhost',
          user     : 'BloodKnight',
          password : 'sasa17',
          database : 'b2b.playstore.loc'
        });
    _this.querys  = {};
    _this.selectors = {};//dom селекторы для Scraping'a
    _this.rows = null;//Массив из url
    _this.workers = 5;//Количество одновременных асинхронных опросов
    _this.needleOptions = {
            follow_max : 5    // Максимум 5 редиректов
            ,headers:{'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; YandexBot/3.0; +http://yandex.com/bots) '}
            ,open_timeout: 2000 // if we don't get our response headers in 5 seconds, boom.
    }
    this.run = function(){
        _this.DB.connect();
        _this.queryLoad();
        _this.resetSelectorsStatus();
    }
    //--------------------// //Загружаем шаблоны запросов {операция блокирующая(синхронная)}
    this.queryLoad = function(){
        _this.querys['selectcSelectors'] = fs.readFileSync('sql/selectcSelectors.sql', 'utf8');
        _this.querys['resetSelectorsStatus'] = fs.readFileSync('sql/resetSelectorsStatus.sql', 'utf8');
        _this.querys['selectcURLs'] = fs.readFileSync('sql/selectcURLs.sql', 'utf8');
        _this.querys['updateCompetitorData'] = fs.readFileSync('sql/updateCompetitorData.sql', 'utf8');


    };
    //--------------------// //Сбрасываем статус селекторов
    this.resetSelectorsStatus = function(callback){
        _this.DB.query(  _this.querys['resetSelectorsStatus'], function(err, rows) {
            _this.selectcSelectors();
        });
    }
    //--------------------// //----Массив DOM електоров
    this.selectcSelectors = function(callback){
        _this.DB.query(  _this.querys['selectcSelectors'] , function(err, rows) {
              if (!err){
                rows.forEach(function(item, i, arr) {
                     if (!_this.selectors[item.competitor_id]){_this.selectors[item.competitor_id]=[];}
                     _this.selectors[item.competitor_id].push({id:item.id,selector:item.selector});
                });
                _this.selectcURLs();
              }
        });
    }
    //--------------------//
    this.selectcURLs = function(callback){
        _this.DB.query(  _this.querys['selectcURLs'] , function(err, rows) {
              if (!err){
                  _this.rows = rows;
                  _this.workersTask(); 
              }
        });
    }
    //--------------------//
    this.workersTask = function(){
        __this = this;
        __this.worker = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < _this.workers; i++) {
            __this.worker[i] = {
                    id:i
                    ,status: 'run'
                    ,allTask : function(){
                        var status = {};
                        status['run'] = 0;
                        status['iddle'] = 0;
                        __this.worker.forEach(function(item){
                            if(item.status==='run'){status['run']++;}
                            else{status['iddle']++;}
                        });
                        return status;
                    }
                    ,timeStart : new Date().valueOf()
                    ,func: function(){
                        _this.parseData(__this.worker[this.id])
                    }
            }
            __this.worker[i].func();
        }
    }
    //--------------------//
    this.parseData = function(worker){
        __this = this;
        var count = _this.rows.length;
        var startTime = new Date().valueOf(); 

        if(count > 0 ){
            var row = _this.rows.shift();//удаляет первый элемент из rows и возвращает его значение
            var URL  = row.competitor_url;
            needle.get(URL, _this.needleOptions, function(err, res){
                if (err) {worker.func(); return;}

                var timeRequest = ( new Date().valueOf() ) - startTime;
                schema.parseContent(res.body, function(schemaObject, $){
                    price = _this.parseBody(schemaObject,$,row);
                    status = ( price!='NULL' ) ? 'active' : 'error';

                    console.log(res.statusCode, 'timeout:'+timeRequest, 'price:'+price, worker.id, URL, row.id);

                    _this.updateCompetitorData({
                                id : row.id
                                ,status:status
                                ,response_time:( new Date().valueOf() )
                                ,response_ms:timeRequest
                                ,price:price
                            });

                    worker.func();
                });

            });
        }else{
            worker.status = 'idle';
            if(worker.allTask().run===0){
                console.log('Мы все завершили, мы молодцы');
                _this.DB.end();//Закрываем соединение с бд;
            }
        }
    }

    _this.parseBody = function(schemaObject,$,row){
        var price;
        schemaObject.elems.forEach(function(elemsItem, i) {
            if(!elemsItem.product)return;
            elemsItem.product.forEach(function(productItem, i) {
                if(!productItem.price)return;
                price = ( productItem.price['content'] ) ? productItem.price['content'] :
                            ( productItem.price['text'] ) ? productItem.price['text'] :
                            null;   
                price = price.match(/[^.\d]+/g, "").replace( /^([^\.]*\.)|\./g, '$1' );
                price = Math.floor(price);  
            });
        });
        if( (!price) && (_this.selectors[row.competitor_id]) ){
            _this.selectors[row.competitor_id].forEach(function(selector){
                price_text = $(selector.selector).text();
                if (price_text){
                    price = price_text.replace(/[^.\d]/g, '').replace( /^([^\.]*\.)|\./g, '$1' );
                    price = Math.floor(price);


                    //Обновляем статус о том что selector был использован
                    //-------------------------------------------------//
                    return;
                }
            });
        }

        if(!price){price = 'NULL'};
        return price;
    }
    //--------------------//
    _this.updateCompetitorData = function(data){
        query = templayed(  _this.querys['updateCompetitorData']  )(data);
        _this.DB.query( query , function(err, rows) {});
    }
    //--------------------//
    _this.run();
}
```

Проблема конкретно в строчке:

```
   if( (!price) && (_this.selectors[row.competitor_id]) ){
            _this.selectors[row.competitor_id].forEach(function(selector){
                price_text = $(selector.selector).text();
                if (price_text){
                    price = price_text.replace(/[^.\d]/g, '').replace( /^([^\.]*\.)|\./g, '$1' );
                    price = Math.floor(price);
```

price = price_text.replace(/[^.\d]/g, '').replace( /^([^.]*.)|./g, '$1' ); - вот здесь, не могу понять как оставить запятую, помогите пожалуйста!

Answer (score 0):

Примерно так:

```js
console.log('299,00 р.'.replace(/[^,\d]/g, ''));
```

Только после этого вы округляете, а округлять с запятой не получится.

Comment: Всмысле округляю? Вы имеете ввиду 2-ой replace?

Comment: @BloodKnight, нет, вот здесь - `price = Math.floor(price);`

Comment: Спасибо большое! Помогло)